# Is there any method to identify cameras has stopped streaming?

Tags: stream, streaming, video-streaming, wowza, wow64

I'm new in Wowza. I need to know whether there is any method to identify cameras has stopped streaming in Wowza?

Comment: Try the [Wowza Engine REST API](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?742-Live-sources-query-examples#getpublishers)

Comment: Thanks Aergistal , let me try with this one.I hope this will work for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. REST API :

> GET /v2/servers/{serverName}/vhosts/{vhostName}/applications/{appName}/instances/{instanceName}
>
> =================================

Try to check Response(bellow):

> IncomingStreamConfig {
>
> ptzPollingInterval (integer),
>
> isRecordingSet (boolean),
>
> sourceIp (string),
>
> applicationInstance (string),
>
> isPTZEnabled (boolean), name (string),
>
> isConnected (boolean),
>
> serverName (string),
>
> isPublishedToVOD (boolean),
>
> saveFieldList (array[string], optional),
>
> version (string),
>
> isStreamManagerStream (boolean)
>
> }

2. Server Side Module :

You can add module to your Wowza Application.

If you are using Eclipse, install Wowza IDE 4.